# Family visitor visa refused, should I apply for dependent visa?

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens, visa-refusals, proof-of-accommodation

My husband got a working visa (TIER 2 (INTRA-COMPANY TRANSFER) VISA
TYPE: SHORT-TERM STAFF MIGRANT, UP TO 1 YEAR) upto april. So I applied for a family visitor visa (in September) for six months. I was rejected stating the reason tht I have no accommodation details, and there is no proof that I would return. Now we are thinking to go for dependent visa, is our decision correct or what am I to do?

Comment: if you got a reply stating what went wrong, why not making sure these details are addressed (i.e. provide accommodation details and proof of return)?

Answer (score 4):

If your husband has a valid T2 ICT visa and both of you are **NOT from North Korea**, you may be able to qualify for a dependent visa depending upon your circumstances.

The most rigorous requirement is the financial hurdle, which will be to show a clear balance of GBP 1,575 (this covers the primary and one dependent).

Because you have a prior refusal you'll need to think up an explanation of what happened. Usually you can just copy it from your refusal letter. But in all events it should make clear how the circumstances have changed.

To proceed, apply on-line at the same site you used for your visitor application.

There is a guidance brochure at https://www.gov.uk/tier-2-intracompany-transfer-worker-visa/family-members

Comment: To add to this correct answer, the earlier family visitor visa wasn't applicable. The [official website](https://www.gov.uk/family-visit-visa/eligibility) clearly states for an FVV that the family member should be British or **settled** in the UK, which wasn't the case here. I'm sure the refusal letter must have mentioned this point. Anyway, this question should be migrated to expats SE.

Answer (score 3):

You could reapply your family visitor visa and provide the necessary documents to support your application. Your husband's finance (income, outgoing, saving etc. using at least the last few months bank statements as proof and make sure the money is able to cover the expenses of your staying with your husband without working), accommodation (a letter from his current landlord, stating that you are allowed to stay in the same accommodation). To prove that you will return you have to show that you have a "strong tie" with your home country: your children(if any), family, property, job etc.